# How to Compare 2 list of string field without join in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I want to compare difference of 4 fileds (2 fields compare to 2 fields)

| customer l6m | item l6m | customer mtd | item mtd | customr add | item add |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 111 | A | 111 | NULL |
| 111 | B | 111 | B | 112 | A |
| 111 | C | 111 | C | 112 | E |
| 111 | D | 112 | A |  |  |
| 112 | B | 112 | B |  |  |
| 112 | C | 112 | C |  |  |
| 112 | D | 112 | D |  |  |
|  |  | 112 | E |  |  |

I want to compare customer l6m & item l6m with customer mtd & item mtd. The comparison is I want to know the new item from item mtd per customer based on the item l6m. Like the result customer add 111 is NULL because all item mtd is in the item l6m and customer 112 have A & E because these items is not in item l6m field.

I dont want use join table because it will be very slow because 1 customer can have 200 item and there are thousands customer but if only can use join maybe you can show me how to solve this too.

Thank you

Comment: The tableau features that can be helpful here are sets and aggregate calculations